# Drupal 7: Reorder the css files

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have included the following css files into my_theme.info file

```
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/all.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/static.css
```

and this files are loading on every page, but my particular css file associated with page is loading before the above css files.
But i want above css files should load first then my page css file load
what i do for that?

Comment: Why not to use `weight` attribute while adding css for that particular page & give it a higher weight value ?

Comment: How is the particular css file associated with the page?

Comment: if my page is http://www.example.com/all-tools and css file for that is all-tools.css this file is loading before the style.css, css/all.css, css/static.css. I want the css files included in my_them.info should be included first on every page

Answer (score 4):

By default css files of theme (as set in mytheme.info file) are loading very last and after any other css files of any module. This is done to override any css if needed.

So, if you want to load the css files **before** any other you should better **add them with [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) function in a custom module** and set their weight as -100 or less (number is just an example of order weight).

To get the path you can use the [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) or [drupal_get_path_alias()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) (for the alias) or any other function/method to get the path.

But, as you said, **these are theme css files** so in your custom module you could also write this in your module:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    // Set theme's path
  $themepath = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme');

  // check current path
    if (current_path() == "internal/path/of/the/page") {
    // add theme css in group CSS_SYSTEM
    drupal_add_css($themepath . '/path/to/mycss.css', array('group' => CSS_SYSTEM, 'type' => 'file', 'weight' => -100));
  }
}
```

The code above will move the mycss.css file to **group "CSS_SYSTEM"** that loads the core css files first and before any other css files from modules (CSS_DEFAULT) or theme (CSS_THEME)